# image won't position at bottom in html

Tags: html, position

I have a menu bar that I want to place at the bottom of my screen. I've set the positioning to absolute and the distance from bottom to '0', but for some reason, it won't move from the middle of the screen, regardless of how I try to position it. Can anyone catch what I am doing wrong?

```
<div class=bmenu>
  <img src="bottommenu.gif" width=100% height="39" alt="" />
</div>

<style>
.bmenu
{
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}
</style>
```

Edit:
Several commenters have said that this code places it at the bottom for them. Does this mean that the problem is coming from the way this code fragment is interacting with the rest of the code? Does anyone know what could cause that?

Comment: Beware of browser compatability. [CssStickFooter](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) also has some useful info.

Comment: Image is @ bottom in Chrome. Describe your browser plz.

Comment: I'm seeing it in the middle in the preview in dreamweaver, as well as in firefox.

Comment: Is the `.bmenu` div inside a container div? If so, the `absolute` declaration would be relative to that parent div.

Comment: probably some css rules is overriding the style

Comment: @Mudshark it will only happen when the parent `div` has `position:relative`?

Comment: @Bob It also happens with a parent `div`which has the default `position:static`I think.

Comment: It doesn't have a parent div, I'm not sure what could be affecting it.

Comment: nope. only when the parent has relative position :) http://jsfiddle.net/y8tD5/1/

Comment: That is the limitation of absolute positioning. It is limited to the height of your active window. `position: fixed` might be the way to go or use a javascript to reposition the button

Answer (score 1):

If you use any of the browser's web inspectors, you'll see that the height of your `<html>` and `<body>` elements aren't 100%, but `auto`, which means they'll only be as tall as the content within them expands them to.

What you need to do is set the height of these elements, like so:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

This will force them to fill the full height of the viewport. The only caveat is that this requires you to define `margin-top`, `margin-bottom`, `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` on other elements, since margins and paddings will be added **on top of the height**, which is not what you normally want when defining `height` (or `width`, for that matter) in `%`.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code:

```
.bmenu
{
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;

}
```

Comment: I appreciate the advice! Unfortunately the page is long enough to need to scroll, and I want the menubar to move in relation to the rest of it, so I don't think that will work?